# Потеря элемента при перезагрузке DataTable

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, .net

Всем привет, моя задача состоит в том, что по нажатию кнопки найти дубликаты строк и по второму клику вернутся к общему списку.

Кнопка:

```
<div id="buttonContainer" style="display: inline-block;">
     <button id="filterButton" class="toggle-button btn btn-info" type="button">Пошук дублів</button>
</div>
```

При первом запуске страницы, выгружаю все элементы такой функцией:

В ней же я вставляю свою кнопку после кнопок самого DataTable (["copy", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"]). Чтобы все кнопки были в одной строке.

```
function loadSideEffectPartial() {
                $('body').find('#SideEffectContainer').load('@Url.Action("SideEffectPartial", "SideEffect")', {
                    buttonText: button_Text
                }, function () {

                    $("#SideEffectTable").DataTable({
                        "responsive": false,
                        "lengthChange": false,
                        "pageLength": 20,
                        "autoWidth": false,
                        "paginate": false,
                        "fixedHeader": true,
                        "scrollY": "600px",
                        "scrollCollapse": true,
                        "scrollX": "100%",
                        "scrollXInner": "100%",
                        "buttons": ["copy", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"],
                        "fixedColumns": {
                            left: 1
                        }
                    }).buttons().container().appendTo('#SideEffectTable_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');


                    $('#buttonContainer').insertAfter('#SideEffectTable_wrapper .dt-buttons');

                    var buttons = $('#SideEffectTable_wrapper .dt-buttons');

                    buttons.addClass('mr-1');
                    
                });
             }
```

В обработчике для кнопки я меняю ее текст, а так же вызываю loadSideEffectPartial(), которая была прописана выше. В loadSideEffectPartial я передаю текущий текст кнопки с помощью переменной button_Text, которая после идет в метод контроллера. В контроллере у меня один метод для выгрузки элементов в котором стоит проверка на текст кнопки.

```
var button_Text = $('#filterButton').text();

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#filterButton").click(function () {
                button_Text = $(this).text();
                $(this).text(button_Text=== "Пошук дублів" ? "Скасувати" : "Пошук дублів");
                loadSideEffectPartial();
            });
        });
```

И вот все элементы выгрузились в таблицу, кнопка для поиска дубликатов на своем месте и при первом клике на нее у меня в таблице уже только дубликаты.

Но после этого кнопка пропадает, ее вообще нет. Я понимаю, что скорее всего это из-за того, что я перезагружаю DataTable. Перепробовал такие варианты как:

1. Удаление таблицы и заново ее отрендерить;
2. Сделать блок кнопки через detach и заново засунуть в таблицу.